# git не реагирует на команду add

Tags: git, github

Пытаюсь залить свой проект на GitHub репозиторий. Работаю в Линуксе. Выполняю вполне стандартные действия

```
git init
git add -A
```

После чего пытаюсь закоммитить

```
git commit -m "my-commit"
```

На что он выдает "На ветке master нечего коммитить, нет изменений в рабочем каталоге".
Я пытался перезапускать терминал, создавал новый репозиторий, удалял origin,но ничего не помогает. До этого заливал проекты на винде, подобных проблем не возникало

Comment: Так может так и есть? git status что говорит?

Comment: Тоже пишет "На ветке master нечего коммитить, нет изменений в рабочем каталоге". Но разве командой add я не добавляю изменения в каталог?

Comment: команда add добавляет измененные файлы в индекс. А сами изменения Вы сами добавляете с помощью редактора или других тулов.